# Objects embedded floating on mobile view really confusing

Tags: javascript, html

I have the below [page](http://vps100011.vps.ovh.ca/) from a website I inherited. Everything is fine when I try different window sizes but if I switch to mobile view in Chrome divs start to float on top of the page.

I just don't understand what makes this happen.

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!doctype html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>www</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="static/favicon.ico">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/StudioHanel/styles/main.css">
        <!-- endbuild -->
        <!-- build:js scripts/vendor/modernizr.js -->
        <script src="{% static "bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js" %}"></script>
        <!-- endbuild -->

    </head>
    <body onLoad="studioHanel.StudioHanel()">
        <!--[if lt IE 10]>
            <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->

        <div class="navbar-fixed-top">
            <img class="logo" src="{% static "images/logo_large.png" %}" alt="Studio Hanel"/>
            <ul id="menu" class="nav nav-pills pull-right"></ul>
        </div>

        <div id="landing">
        </div>

        <div id="teaser-about" class="teaser">
            <h1></h1>
            <div class="arrow"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="about">
            <div class="container-fluid">

            <div class="header"></div>
            <h1></h1>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div id="about-copy-column" class="col-md-8"><div class="two-columns"></div></div>
                    <div id="about-photo-column" class="col-md-4"><img src="{% static "images/cordelia_old.png" %}" width="244" height="274"></div>
                </div>
            </div> 

            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="interiors">
            <div class="container-fluid"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="teaser-interiors" class="teaser">
            <div class="shadow-up"></div>
            <div class="pattern"></div>
            <h2></h2>
            <div class="shadow-down"></div>
            <div class="arrow"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="case-study">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div id="cell1" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"></div>
                    <div id="cell2" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">    
                    <div id="cell3" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"></div>
                    <div id="cell4" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">    
                    <div id="cell5" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"></div>
                    <div id="cell6" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="product-design">

        </div>

        <div id="teaser-contact" class="teaser">
            <h2></h2>
            <div class="arrow"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="contact-util"></div>

        <div id="contact">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-7" id="contact-form">
                        <form name="contact" action="" method="">
                            <fieldset>
                                <input id="name" class="text-input" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your name"> 
                                <input id="email" class="text-input" type="text" name="sender" placeholder="Your email">
                                <input id="message" class="text-input" type="text" name="message" placeholder="What's on your mind?">
                                <label id="error"></label>
                                <input id="send" class="button" type="button" value="Send">
                                <!--<input id="send" class="button" name="submit" value="Send">-->
                            </fieldset>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div id="contact-details">
                            <div id="phone" class="contact-details"></div>
                            <div id="address" class="contact-details"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="shadow-up"></div>
            <div class="pattern"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="copyright">
            <p>&copy; Studio Hanel 2014   All rights reserved including all imagery as shown on this website</p>
        </div>

        <!-- build:js scripts/vendor.js -->
        <!-- bower:js -->
        <script src="{% static "bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js" %}"></script>
        <!-- <script src="{% static "bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js" %}"></script> -->
        <script src="{% static "bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js" %}"></script>
        <!-- <script src="{% static "bower_components/greensock/src/uncompressed/TweenMax.js" %}"></script> -->
        <script src="{% static "bower_components/gsap/src/uncompressed/TweenMax.js" %}"></script>

        <!-- <script src="{% static "bower_components/greensock/src/uncompressed/plugins/ScrollToPlugin.js" %}"></script> -->
        <script src="{% static "bower_components/gsap/src/uncompressed/plugins/ScrollToPlugin.js" %}"></script>
        <!-- <script src="{% static "bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/scrollbars.js" %}"></script> -->
        <!-- endbower -->
        <!-- endbuild -->

        <!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID. -->
        <script>
            (function(b,o,i,l,e,r){b.GoogleAnalyticsObject=l;b[l]||(b[l]=
            function(){(b[l].q=b[l].q||[]).push(arguments)});b[l].l=+new Date;
            e=o.createElement(i);r=o.getElementsByTagName(i)[0];
            e.src='//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js';
            r.parentNode.insertBefore(e,r)}(window,document,'script','ga'));
            ga('create','UA-XXXXX-X');ga('send','pageview');
        </script>
<!-- 
        <script src="{% static "bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/affix.js" %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static "bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/alert.js" %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static "bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/dropdown.js" %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static "bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/tooltip.js" %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static "bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/modal.js" %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static "bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/transition.js" %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static "bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/button.js" %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static "bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/popover.js" %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static "bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/carousel.js" %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static "bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/scrollspy.js" %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static "bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/collapse.js" %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static "bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/tab.js" %}"></script> -->

        <!-- build:js scripts/plugins.js -->
        <script src="{% static "bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/affix.js" %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static "bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/alert.js" %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static "bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/dropdown.js" %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static "bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/tooltip.js" %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static "bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/modal.js" %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static "bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/transition.js" %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static "bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/button.js" %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static "bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/popover.js" %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static "bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/carousel.js" %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static "bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/scrollspy.js" %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static "bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/collapse.js" %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static "bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/tab.js" %}"></script>
        <!-- endbuild -->

        <!-- build:js({app,.tmp}) scripts/main.js -->
        <script src="{% static "scripts/utils.js" %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static "scripts/landing.js" %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static "scripts/about.js" %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static "scripts/interiors.js" %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static "scripts/case_study.js" %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static "scripts/product_design.js" %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static "scripts/contact.js" %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static "scripts/menu.js" %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static "scripts/navigation.js" %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static "scripts/main.js" %}"></script>
        <!-- endbuild -->
</body>
</html>
```

**main.css**
can't be posted due to large size.

can be downloaded from [here](http://vps100011.vps.ovh.ca/static/StudioHanel/styles/main.css)

Comment: Post your CSS code

Comment: thank the response .... unfortunately It's way big you can download from http://vps100011.vps.ovh.ca/static/StudioHanel/styles/main.css

Comment: Sorry didn't see bootstrap is responsible for responsiveness. You can fix the overlapping by putting your logo's image inside other div and hiding it for small screens.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be the logo and nav bar overlapping.

To fix this you can wrap the logo with a div and use the bootstrap's class `hidden-xs` like this:

```
<div class="navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="hidden-xs">
        <img class="logo" src="{% static "images/logo_large.png" %}" alt="Studio Hanel"/>
    </div>
    <ul id="menu" class="nav nav-pills pull-right"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Didn't help much. but thanks, I just don't understand why the width of the "Welcome screen" section changes from half-width to full-width as I scroll down. And it only happens if I switch to  mobile view not even when the screen width is small.

Comment: Firefox wasn't breaking, seems to be something with the `position: absolute` css attribute on the panels

Comment: No I am using the chrome mobile (eg. Galaxy S5)...like I said things are fine if I narrow/tighten the browser width. As another example there is a div #landing which has width = 100% but it doesn't fill the whole width of the device.